# Serialization of extended Tree Structure

Tags: c++, serialization, tree

I have a tree-like structure, which is constructed by

```c
struct TreeNode
{
     std::vector<TreeNode*> p_PrevLevelNodes;
     std::vector<TreeNode*> p_NextLevelNodes;
}
```

and there is some root node stored. In contrast to a classical tree, a Node might have multiple root nodes. All of these root nodes are present in the "classical" tree, but there are so to say additional link ups.

To come to my question: I have to communicate this structure between different instances by both MPI and tcp. Hence, I need some kind of serialization, but dont really know where to start.

Any hints?

Comment: "I have a tree-like structure, which is constructed by"... No, you don't. That isn't even legal C++.

Comment: Well, I am quite sure that I have a tree-like structure. However, I use it like that, as long there is only one PrevLevel pointer. Every node has multiple sub-nodes. Sorry for placing the * at the wrong position, but I am searching for a general idea, not exact code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your tree? Your tree is a pointer `pRoot` to one of such nodes (`TreeNode`). Since you have `pRoot`, you can build list of upper nodes (it is empty for `pRoot` in usual situation) and list of lower nodes. So you can build list of visited nodes + save additional information about them. And for each of these nodes in list you can repeat all these operations. So you will have big list of nodes with additional information - it is easy to serialize this list instead of you tree.

(Actually it is not necessary to build intermidiate data structure to serialize, but I propose to remember about this structure to simplify implementation of you algorithm)

Something similar was implemented here: http://basicalgos.blogspot.ru/2012/04/44-serialize-and-de-serialize-tree.html (there is much simplier tree, but I think you can repeat this logic for your tree).

Also it might be useful for you to read http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/29/an-interesting-tree-serialization-algorithm-from-dwarf/